# Play MP3-files (C# Forms)

Tags: c#, forms, audio, mp3

I'm trying to play an MP3 sound. I have made a reference to MediaPlayer (*Interop.MediaPlayer.dll* and *Interop.WMPLib.dll*). Then I have this code

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
    wplayer.URL = @"D:\test.mp3";
    wplayer.controls.play();
}
```

I get no errors, but I get no sound at all... Also, is it possible to play MP3 sounds without adding any .dll's to the application folder?

Comment: Your code should play. Check your volume. If you can't get it to work, I suggest using NAudio instead of MediaPlayer: http://naudio.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MP3

Comment: I'll try that out. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following code in the past to play MP3 files from C#. I am not sure if this would require adding any dlls to the application folder. I would have to create a new project to test that out.

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
private static extern long mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, StringBuilder lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);

public void playMP3File(string fileName)
{
    string CommandString = "open " + "\"" + fileName + "\"" + " type MPEGVideo alias Mp3File";
    mciSendString(CommandString, null, 0, 0);
    CommandString = "play Mp3File";
    mciSendString(CommandString, null, 0, 0);
}
```